# Loading different DataSpaces when creating MetadataWorkspace from Assembly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Edit: I found out that if I create the workspace from a context (`var workspace = 
 ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;`) the other Dataspaces actually contain item collections instead of null. So I guess the question now is : How can I access CSpace, CSSpace, etc, without instantiating a DbContext?

I'm trying to load the ItemCollections from a MetaDataWorkSpace that I created using a bunch of Assemblies. To eliminate possible mistakes I made a simple class library containing the models, built it, did a code-first migration and I'm now loading the .dll that was created in the process.

The code for the models can be found here: https://pastebin.com/sfziddix (shouldn't be important though)

This is the DbContext:

```
namespace SampleMappingAssembly
{
    class AnimalContext:DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
        public AnimalContext()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to load the Assemblies, transform them into a MetadataWorkspace and load the ItemCollections associated with each DataSpace. The code for this is  the following:

```
namespace WorkSpaceLoader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //The directory where the .dll is
            string directory = @"D:\Zwischenablage\LiterallyCodeFirst";
            //Filter because there's more files in this than just the ones I want to load
            var assemblyPaths = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
                .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".dll") && s.Contains("Sample"));
            var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
            foreach(string path in assemblyPaths)
            {
                try
                {
                    //One of these is an assembly which I can't load due to unrelated reasons so Try-Catch
                    assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(path));
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't load {path.Split('\\').Last()}:\n{ex.Message}\n");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully loaded {assemblies.Count} assemblies. Creating workSpace...");
            //Not sure about the res:// part, but according to my book it's the pattern to look at every DataSpace
            var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace(new string[] {@"res://*"}, assemblies); //@"res://*/"
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully converted assemblies to MetadataWorkspace...");
            List<ItemCollection> coll = new List<ItemCollection>();
            //Iterating over DataSpaces
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4 ; i++)
            {
                var collection = GetItemsFromDataSpace(workspace, (DataSpace)i);
                if (collection != null)
                    coll.Add(collection);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nDone loading ItemCollections");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static ItemCollection GetItemsFromDataSpace(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DataSpace dataSpace)
        {
            ItemCollection items;
            try
            {
                //Not using TryGetItemCollection because I wanted to see the exception
                items = workspace.GetItemCollection(dataSpace);
                Console.WriteLine($"\nSuccessfully retrieved ItemCollection from {dataSpace.ToString()}");
                return items;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nUnable to retrieve Item collection from {dataSpace.ToString()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\n{ex.ToString()}\n");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which gives the following result (printing the Exceptions in the console):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwB1g.png

I must admit, my understanding of the topic is fairly limited but now I really am at a wall. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, only the `OSpace` ("Object Space") contains actual collections of objects. The other spaces merely consist of metadata describing the DB Model, contained relations / mappings, etc... (Maybe have a look at [this link for further informations on wording used in EF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/04/03/tip-10-how-to-understand-entity-framework-jargon/)). Why are you trying to get Items from a different space than the `OSpace`?

Comment: The thing I am actually interested in are the custom mappings, as I'm trying to read them. I'm working on a tool that's supposed to take a look at EF-Metadata and validate the conceptual model (=C-Space? CS-Space?) against the Meta-Data Tables on the respective database server.